What shape do you get by sweeping a cube through 4D space?
If you sweep a 1D line through a 2D space in a circular motion, you get a disc with a hole.
The path of the line would be x=cos(a) y=sin(a)
If you sweep a 2D square through 3D space in a circular motion, you get a doughnut.
The path of the square would be x=cos(a) y=sin(a) z=0
If I were to sweep a 3D cube through 4D space in a circular motion, what would I get?
The path of the cube would be x=cos(a) y=sin(a) z=0 w=0


It actually depends on the position of your cube, but "generically" and assuming that the cube is disjoint from the plane of rotation, a topologist would call the result $B^3\times S^1$. More generally, if you do this in $\mathbb R^n$, the result is $B^{n-1}\times S^1$.

@MoisheKohan A perspective wireframe projection would look like a ‘doughnut’ (as the OP puts it) trapped inside another wireframe donut, right? Like an inner tubing inside a cycle wheel tube?

Only the first two dimensions are involved in your rotation operation. Your $(n+2)$-dimensional cube turns into the Cartesian product of your 2D doughnut with an $n$-dimensional cube.

I assume that the rotation takes place in the $xy$-plane. To describe something that matches your pictures it may be simplest to use polar coordinates in the $xy$-plane, and let $z,w,\ldots$ be as they are. So $n$-dimensional cylindrical coordinates, if you wish.  You seem to want $r\in[1,2]$, $\phi\in[0,2\pi)$, $z\in[0,1[$, $w\in[0,1]$ etc. The set of points is then parametrized by $(r\cos\phi, r\sin\phi, z,w,\ldots)$. So a cartesian product of that annulus and an $(n-2)$-dimensional unit cube. Further broken down in Moishe Kohan's comment.
